# Which scenario to use parallel stream over sequential stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am confused about the usage of parallel stream in java 8. Could anyone suggest me at which scenario's to go for parallel streams.

Answer (score -2):

Parallel stream is the process of dividing the content of a stream into multiple data blocks and using different threads to process each stream of different data blocks separately.\

The default ForkJoinPool thread pool is used internally for parallel stream. The default number of threads is the number of cores in the processor. A JVM only has one parallel stream thread pool, which means that all parallel streams share a set of computing resources.

Parallel stream itself does not guarantee thread safety, and it is not recommended to use parallel stream when there are operations to modify shared variables in the code.

So I suggest trying to use parallel streams when there is a large amount of data and there is a high split type of low consumption operation.

To consider the total computational cost of the flow operation pipeline, assuming N is the total number of tasks to be operated on and Q is the time for each operation. N * Q is the total operation time, and a higher Q value means that the possibility of using parallel streams to bring benefits is greater, but at the same time, the risk is also higher, after all, shared computing resources.\

For high concurrency interfaces, parallel flow is not recommended. You can manually create a controllable custom thread pool and use it to perform these tasks.